# GWT detach widget from DOM and add to Panel

Tags: java, gwt, gwtquery

I need to be able to detach a node from the `DOM` and attach it to a `HorizontalPanel` at runtime using `GwtQuery`.

My code looks like this:

```
    @PageShown
    public void pageReady() {
        horizontalPanel.add($("#bar1").widget());
        horizontalPanel.add($("#bar2").widget()); 
        horizontalPanel.add($("#bar3").widget());   
    }
```

Where `#bar1`, et. al are already attached in the DOM, what I need to do is that these 3 bars should be piled horizontally so I need to attach them to a HorizontalPanel.

**Update:**

After promoting the DOM element into Panel the `horizontalPanel` is still empty:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" data-field="navPanel"><tbody><tr></tr></tbody></table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$("#bar1")` should be a gwt-widget, otherwise the method `widget()` of gQuery will return null.

You can, though, promote certain dom-elements to widgets with gQuery:

```
    // Promote 3 elements attached to the dom to 3 GWT Panel Widgets
    $("#bar1, #bar2, #bar3").as(Widgets).panel();

    horizontalPanel.add($("#bar1").widget());
    horizontalPanel.add($("#bar2").widget()); 
    horizontalPanel.add($("#bar3").widget());
```

Apart from `panel()` which promotes an element to a GWT `Panel`, the gQuery `Widgets` plugin comes with other predefined methods like `label()` `textBox()` `passwordBox()` and `textArea()`. But you can code your own `WidgetFactory` to promote any dom element to customized widgets through the method `widgets(WidgetFactory)`.

Anyway, if you only want to layout elements in your page, an easier way could be just use css instead of wrapping them into widgets.

Comment: Since I'm using Errai, #bar's 1-3 are actually, 2 IFRAMEs, and one DIV styled as nav. Can an iframe tag be promoted into a widget without loosing its content? Also same with the DIVs will it loose its content that is hard-coded in the HTML template? As for the layout I would like to use GWT to have maximum compatibility with browsers.

Comment: Yes, `Widgets.panel()` supports `<iframe>`, `<div>` and almost any element.

Comment: Note that the element should be in the dom in order that `$("#bar1")` returns it, otherwise you have to specify the context where the element is attached: `$("#bar1", mywidget)`

Comment: $("#bar1, #bar2, #bar3").as(Widgets).panel(); // Compile-time error, can you link a actual working code?

Comment: Uhm, it should be Widgets.Widgets? And I did what you said, I checked the DOM and the horizontalPanel is still empty.

Comment: When using GQuery normally we use `import static com.google.gwt.query.client.GQuery.*;` so many vars and methods are available (like Widgets).

Comment: I double checked, and that works for me, test that all the stuff is in the dom before calling `panel()`. I'm using gquery 1.4.0-SNAPSHOT btw.